# Spring JPA MongoRepository causes "duplicate key" error rather than updating document

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a field ID in my model:

```
@Field(value = "_id")
private ObjectId Id;
```

and a DB Entry:

```
_id: ObjectId("5a7ecec9bd9bd72884484bc4")
name:"October"
```

my repository just extends MongoRepository, no extra methods. 
The goal is to update the Document. 
The problem is that MongoRepository does not have any  `update`  methods, so I read a couple articles and figured out that  `save`  method updates documents if finds existing ones with same "Id" in DB, if not - creates new Entry. The other method -  `insert`  - does not look for existing "Id" and just tries to create new Document.
As I understand  `insert`  can possibly cause  `E11000 duplicate key error`, but in my case this error appears in both methods:  `save, insert` 
Why  `save`  can cause duplicate error ? Is there any different ways to update Document with MongoRepository ?

Comment: Could you please post your repository method definition?

Comment: use @Id annotation instead of @Field(value = "_id")